# Group Items With MSSQL and Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I have the following table:

```
Name    Type    Color    Place
Ana     A       Blue     America
Sandra  A       Red      India
Mary    A       Red      America
Paige   B       Orange   Africa
Fox     B       White    Africa
John    C       Black    Mexico
```

I would like to group the itens by type and show, like this:

```
Type A
Ana - Blue - America
Sandra - Red - India
Mary - Red - America

Type B
Paige - Orange - Africa
Fox - White - Africa

Type C
John - Black - Mexico
```

What kinda of loop will help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just select you records, ordering by Type, and then loop through the recordset.

Keep track of the Type in a variable, and whenever the Type changes, add a line break before writing out the next Type.

**EDIT:** For example:

```
<%
    Dim strType

    do while not rs.EOF
        if strType <> rs("Type") then  ' <---- check if the types are different here
            Response.Write "Type " & rs("Type") & "<BR><BR>"
        end if

        ' your user records go here

        strType = rs("Type")  ' <---- set the strType variable before looping
        rs.MoveNext
   loop
%>
```

Comment: How to find this: "...and whenever the Type changes"? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select Name, Color, Place 
from MyTable
order by Type
```

Then in your ASP code, when Type value is not the same as previous Type (or is first row), print out your Type header row.

Comment: How to find this: "when Type value is not the same as previous Type"? Thanks

Comment: Use a variable to persist the previous type value as you iterate.